# php- login validations not working

Tags: php, html, validation

This is my first time validating a form.
I have got stuck on validating the email in theory it seems like it should work but it doesn't.

The following code only works when i remove the email validation:
     if ($c_pass1 == $c_pass2) {
      } else {
                    echo "**Oops! Your passwords do not match** ";

not to sure where i have gone wrong. The validation literally does nothing. is there a better way to validate an email address?

HTML

```
            <!--                    <div id="first">-->
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value='' required><!--<span class="error"><?php //echo $c_emailErr; ?></span>-->
            <br>

            <figure>
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" value="" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><?php //echo $c_pass1Err; ?></span>-->
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" value="" placeholder=" Confirm password" maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><?php //echo $c_pass2Err; ?></span>-->
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </figure>
            <p class="remember_me">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">
            <br>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
            $c_email = $_POST['email'];
            $c_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
            $c_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
            $c_emailErr = $c_pass1Err = $c_pass2Err = "";

         if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        //Validates email
         if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $c_emailErr  = "You Forgot to Enter Your Email!";
       } else {
       $c_email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
       // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
      if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$c_emailErr )) {
        $c_emailErr  = "You Entered An Invalid Email Format"; 
      }
}

            if ($c_pass1 == $c_pass2) {

                $q = "INSERT INTO    Cus_Register(Cus_Email,Cus_Password,Cus_confirm_password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
                //new
                // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
                //debugging
                //$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $c_email, $c_pass1, $c_pass2);


                if ($q) {
                    echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
            }
       }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Try to echo out the values of `$c_pass1` and `$c_pass2` to see if they matches

Comment: @luweiqi yeah it matches. thats the only part that works. the registration works too. just the email validation doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate Email Instead Of doing this: `if (empty($_POST["email"])) {` Try doing this `if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false`

That should take care of the email part

Now for the password part try this:

```
if ($_POST[$c_pass1 != $c_pass2]) {echo'wrong password';}else{echo 'good password';}
```